# Trouble with permession Facebook Graph Api in .net

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a c# application that uses Graph api to interact with facebook platform.
Now I'm trying to post a message on wall of a friend and I 've this error

(OAuthException) (#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application

I used this code (csUserId is string with id of a valid user, if I put "me" it works, with a user code it gives exception=

```
dynamic cRes = m_cFB.Post("/"+csUserId+"/feed", new
                {
                    message = "Final Test",
                    link = "http://www.test.it"
                });
```

I found on net several solutions, like Disable "February 2013 Breaking Changes", but I didn't find it in my application settings.
I found only those ones
July 2013 Breaking Changes:
October 2013 Breaking Changes
and I disabled them.
As authorizations I set

User & Friend Permissions: 
user_birthday user_likes friends_birthday friends_likes

Autorizzazioni aggiuntive: 
publish_stream read_stream read_friendlists

But exception still occurrs. Could you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ability to post on friend's wall has been depreciated by the Facebook. Quoting from the Developer Roadmap

> We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API. Specifically, posts against `[user_id]/feed` where `[user_id]` is different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the target_id user is different from the session user, will fail. If you want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). Stories that include friends via [user mentions tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/) or [action tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#taggingpeople/) will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag). For more info, see this [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/).

Also the ability to disable the breaking change will not be available as this has already  gone into effect permanently for everyone.

Comment: Hi Anvesh, thanks for your reply. It's clear what you say, but I've a doubt. Calling feed dialog requires user interaction with ui. What I need is to post to wall in automatic way, without user interaction with a dialog. Is it possible? On feed dialog documentation it says "Your app can also publish directly to a profile's timeline without interaction on the part of people using your app. To do this, use a publishing Graph API call."..but it's depreciated or not? Thanks

Comment: Simply put, you cannot post to a friend's wall automatically now. Also, the documentation doesn't seems to clarify the same clearly, you can still post automatically on current user's wall but not on his friend's wall. I hope this clarifies any further doubt you might have.

Comment: thanks for your reply...I understood this is not possible, I'm trying now to act with tag

dynamic cRes = m_cFB.Post("/me/feed", new
                {
                    message = "Final Test4",
                    place =?                     
                    link = "http://www.test.it",
                    tags = 1505689007
                });

following documentation I don't understand what I've to put in place? Maybe this alternative solution to notify post to friend of a user?Thanks